Checking if a value is 0 and replacing it with NULL in Azure Data Factory
I feel dumb for asking this.
I have a column with thousands of rows. Whenever a value is "0" I want to NULL it.
Currently:
material, clabs
12345, 0
6789,  0
43543, 10
3243,  2

After transformation:
12345, null
6789,  null
43543, 10
3243,  2

I used a derive column with this expression:
columnname: clabs
expression: iif(CLABS == 0, null(), CLABS)
ADF always underlines the second CLABS occurence. I put it in backticks, quotationmarks and everything. Where is my mistake? Of course I dont have to have the string "NULL" but really null.


In the above expression, the returned data type should match in if and else case. Here, both null and integer types are different. So, convert null to the clabs data type like below.
iif(clabs ==  0, toInteger(null()), clabs)

Result:

